# Filtering categorized View Panel in xPages

Tags: xpages

I have a view panel with a categorized view as it source.  The data I am viewing can have various statuses (Status='Submitted' , Status = 'Approved') etc.

I have a combo box on my page that lets me to select the status to display in the view.   That all works great with the exception that the xPages view does the same annoying thing as in the client when displaying a categorized view.  And that is, it does not display the categorized columns then a full text index search filter is in place.

Other than creating a view and a corresponding xpage for each status, is there any way to filter by status and still display the categorized field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need 2 views or 2 view panels on XPage.In the view that was categorized by Status, put the below formula for the categorized Status column :

```
Status : "All"
```

The above formula will add category 'All', and shows all documents irrespective of status.

Comment: Excellent idea and so simple.    Why didn't I think of that? :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right:
You want to use "single category" to select by "Status" (e.g. "Draft") and still want to show the column with "Draft"?
.... besides that you probably would be better off to just show it at a header above the view, since it saves you a full column, you simply add another column to your view (unsorted) that repeats the field "Status". If you don't want to add a view column, you can create a computed column that uses the status field.

Comment: That won't work.  The problem is my "All" view.  Since there is no category filter for all it will first be sorted by status.  So what ends up happening in the "All" view is that the Client name is not categorized when the statuses are different (makes sense).  I think I am going to need two different views.  One categorized by status then client and the other just categorized by client.

Answer (score 0):

I went with two view panels / views.   If "All" is selected then the view that is categorized by client is displayed.  Otherwise the view categorized by status then client is displayed.  The category filter is then used for that view.

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
            xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1"
            viewName="vwRequestsAllByClientsName">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v = getComponent("comboBoxFilterBy").getValue();
 return (v=="All" || v==null);
}]]></xp:this.rendered>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ClientName" id="viewColumn1">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="ClientName"
            id="viewColumnHeader1">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="RequestNum" id="viewColumn2">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Request #"
            id="viewColumnHeader2">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="APPSNo" id="viewColumn3">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="APPS Number"
            id="viewColumnHeader3">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="LoanType" id="viewColumn4">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Loan Type"
            id="viewColumnHeader4">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="LoanAmount" id="viewColumn5">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Loan Amount"
            id="viewColumnHeader5">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Term" id="viewColumn6">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Term" id="viewColumnHeader6">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>

</xp:viewPanel>
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel2">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
            xp:key="headerPager" id="pager2">
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view2"
            viewName="vwRequestsAllByStatusClientsName">
            <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v = getComponent("comboBoxFilterBy").getValue();
```

v}]]>